# type 'string' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' flutter grouped listview inside futurebuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder, grouped-list

In my flutter app,  I'm trying to display the bookmarks grouped by particular field, that's why, I'm using a **grouped list**. The problem is when I use a static list, it shows correctly. But when I try to make the list dynamic by placing grouped listview inside a futurebuilder, and get data from shared preferences I get this error:

type 'string' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

```
class _BookmarkScreenState extends State<BookmarkScreen> {
  List bookmarks =[];


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     _loadData();

    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<List<String>> _loadData() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<String> lb = await pref.getStringList(('bookmarks_key'));
    print(lb);
    lb.forEach((element) {
      bookmarks.add(element);
    });

    print(bookmarks);
    return bookmarks;
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Bookmark Screen")),
        body: Container(
            child: FutureBuilder(
    future: _loadData(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    } else {
                return GroupedListView<dynamic, String>(  // this is the error line
                elements: bookmarks,
                groupBy: (element) => element['surah_name'],
                groupComparator: (value1, value2) => value2.compareTo(value1),
                itemComparator: (item1, item2) =>
                    item1['verse_no'].compareTo(item2['verse_no']),
                order: GroupedListOrder.DESC,
                useStickyGroupSeparators: true,
                groupSeparatorBuilder: (String value) => Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      value,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    )),
                itemBuilder: ((c, element) {
                  return Card(
                    elevation: 8.0,
                    margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 6.0),
                    child: Container(
                      child: ListTile(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
                        title: Text(element['verse_no'].toString()),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }));}})));
  }
}
```

If we remove the loadData function and futurebuilder and use a static list like this :

```
List bookmarks = [{"surah_no":2,"verse_no":2,"surah_name":"Al-Baqarah","favorite":true}, {"surah_no":2,"verse_no":1,"surah_name":"Al-Baqarah","favorite":true}, {"surah_no":2,"verse_no":2,"surah_name":"Al-Baqarah","favorite":true}, {"surah_no":2,"verse_no":3,"surah_name":"Al-Baqarah","favorite":true}, {"surah_no":4,"verse_no":1,"surah_name":"An-Nisa'","favorite":true}, {"surah_no":8,"verse_no":1,"surah_name":"Al-Anfal","favorite":true},];
```

the list is displayed in correct order. Please help what's going wrong while loading data from sheared preferences and displaying in grouped listview?

Comment: how you are vaing items

Comment: storing them in shared preferences as a stringList, then reading those in this bookmarks screen.

Answer (score 0):

static list `bookmarks` works because it contains maps that are used by `groupBy` to create group.

Storing and getting  List wont provide group view for most case like you are doing `element['surah_name']`

Now to fetch the list and just showing item you can
do `groupBy: (element) =>""` with `return GroupedListView<String, String>(`

Create a map store on database and then use on group `GroupedListView`

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer? How am I supposed to create a map on database when I'm already using shared preferences to store & retrieve data..